# How to ignore the prefix api route in express for any action?

Tags: node.js, express

index.js

```
app.use('', routes);
```

routes.js

```
app.get('/comments', (req, res) => {

});

app.get('/posts/:id/comments', (req, res) => {

});

app.post('/comments', (req, res) => {

});

app.delete('/comments/:id', (req, res) => {

});

app.put('/comments/:id', (req, res) => {

});
```

I want to prefix all routes with '/comments/' except the one with the following full path: '/posts/:id/comments'. Is this possible to do without creating a new set of routes? I don't want to make another file with the name "routes2.js". I would like to use app.use('/comments/', routes); without having to create another set of routes so I can avoid repeating myself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can try this in your 
index.js

```
 routes=require('path/to/routes.js')
  //move this route out of routes.js
 app.get('/posts/:id/comments', (req, res) => {

  });

 app.use('/comments', routes);
```

and in your 
routes.js

```
router=require('express').Router

router.get('/', (req, res) => {

});

router.post('/', (req, res) => {

});

router.delete('/', (req, res) => {

});

router.put('/', (req, res) => {

});

exports.module=router
```

Comment: I would get '/comments/posts/:id' and not '/posts/:id/comments'